# YA ClassNotFoundException involving the URLClassLoader

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception, geotools, urlclassloader

After looking through dozens of other SO questions involving these two classes, I've come to the conclusion that this might be a new one.

The code in question involves Eclipse (kepler), Maven, and GeoTools - specifically, a copy of ImageLab from their tutorial, which I've stripped down partially to play with the Style classes. I changed one bit of code to create an RGB style to replace the grayscale style the example uses - and suddenly I get a ClassNotFoundException on this snippet:

```
    Layer rasterLayer = new GridReaderLayer(reader, rgbStyle);
```

If I put a breakpoint there and step into that constructor, I immediately get the CNFE on org.geotools.data.FeatureSource. This is a fairly frequently used class, though, in the gt-api jar, and it's already downloaded and sitting in my Maven Dependencies folder. In fact, I can even stick this in above that line:

```
    FeatureSource<?,?> source = null;
```

...this compiles happily, and it *still* throws a CNFE on that constructor after it. It finds it, and then it can't find it??

That CNFE is being caught and eaten silently, apparently, if I just run the app without using debug mode - it later throws an NPE when it finds that Layer's style object is null.

I've tried restarting Eclipse, and running Project>Clean several times - same problem. gt-api.jar (specifically, gt-api-12-RC1.jar) is in the build path for that project. I can't step into the URLClassLoader, to see where it's looking; or at least, I don't know how.

Can anyone please explain this bizarre behavior, or better, suggest a solution? Alternately, can anyone tell me how I might get a better look at what the URLClassLoader is doing, or what it thinks its classpath is?

Comment: today there are a lot of questions about ClassNotFoundException on stackoverflow. Is everyday like this here (I haven't visited this site for a while), or there's some cosmic event happening right now? :)

Comment: I can at least say this, the line `FeatureSource<?,?> source = null;` will not cause JVM to load the class.

Comment: Bleargh. You're right. I created an anonymous FeatureSource instance there instead, and that avoided the CNFE. (Although the code still doesn't work...) Still, I'd like to know just what the cotton socks is going on there...

Comment: A full stack trace of the CNFE would be useful!